# Endless AWS lambda requests to read and write from/to s3 to the same bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, bucket

I uploaded a code to aws lambda that was supposed to read json files from a "folder" in a bucket, process it and then save them back to the same bucket different folder. I didn't set any event to trigger the lambda, I just tested it and it resulted in hundreds of thousands of lambda requests which I just noticed the following day when I checked the CloudWatch Logs. I am now trying to figure out what went wrong, so far what makes more sense is the idea that I can't read and write to the same bucket even using different prefixes to distinguish the "path", how accurate is that? 
Thanks in advance

this is the python code I was using in lambda:

```
 # load jsons from s3 bucket
def load_s3_jsons(platform):
    s3_path = 'unprocessed-jsons/' + platform + '/'
    keys = get_s3_object_keys(s3_path)

    all_jsons = []
    for key in keys:
        json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        json_reader = json_object['Body'].read()
        all_jsons.append(json.loads(json_reader))

    return all_jsons


def get_s3_object_keys(path):
    # get the list of objects in the bucket with the path prefix
    s3_list_objects = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=path)['Contents']

    # get the keys from files that end with .json
    keys = [item['Key'] for item in s3_list_objects if item['Key'].endswith('.json')]

    # sort keys putting the most recent version first
    keys.sort(key=lambda x: ((''.join(filter(str.isdigit, x))), len(x)), reverse=True)

    return keys


# upload comparison results to s3
def upload_to_s3(platform, version, data):
    s3_path = 'json-results/' + platform + '/'
    upload_byte_stream = bytes(json.dumps(data).encode('UTF-8'))
    filename = version + '.json'
    s3_resource.Object(bucket, s3_path + filename).put(Body=upload_byte_stream)
```

Comment: What is your lambda handler?

Comment: lambda_function.lambda_handler.   In the `def lambda_handler(event, context)`, I called the `loads_s3_jsons` method, processed the results calling another method and lastly I called the `upload_to_s3` method

Comment: AWS Lambda functions will not just magically be executed. _Something_ caused it to happen. You should check the "Trigger" section in the function definition to see whether it is linked to something. You could also look at the S3 bucket settings to see whether an Event is defined that links to the Lambda function. If you wish, you can check your **AWS CloudTrail** logs to see how the Lambda function was executed. It should show the credentials that invoked it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yeah you were right, s3 bucket settings had an event defined linked to the lambda function. Such a stupid mistake :(   thanks